# Is it possible to have more than one WiFi e-PCI card in a single computer?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I am looking into building a network with one main server and X clients which communicate with the main server via WiFi 5Ghz.

The requirements are such that each client needs to use over 1Gb/s of data whenever they are in use. In other words, they each need a full WiFi channel.

So I am thinking that if I want to be able to handle 5 clients, I will need to install 5 PCI-e cards in the main server and assign a specific channel to each one (along a specific range of IP addresses for each WiFi device.)

Is that possible?

From what I am reading, the channels of 5Ghz were designed in such a way that they won't interfere with each others. Yet I have my doubts. If a single server has 5 cards, wouldn't that still generate much interference?

Are there 5Ghz routers that would support multiple channels? (I could not find such in Google, but I may not be using the correct terms to search for them?!)

Note: I'm more interested about the hardware / airwaves potential problems in such a solution. I do not foresee any specific problems with the settings and making things work smoothly on a Linux network, assuming the hardware is capable of such feats.

Comment: You're not going to get many full-bandwidth 5GHz channels, certainly not 5.

Comment: https://community.extremenetworks.com/extreme/topics/what-are-the-5ghz-non-dfs-non-overlapping-channels#reply-15372944-author

Comment: If you have demanding speed requirements, why not used Ethernet? WLAN and guaranteed high-speed don't mix very well.

Answer (score 2):

This will not work in practice.

The [total theoretical bandwidth available using 802.11ac](https://www.extremetech.com/computing/160837-what-is-802-11ac-and-how-much-faster-than-802-11n-is-it) is a fraction under 7Gbps - however you will not come close to reaching this theoretical figure in any real-world setting - and even then its dependent on jurisdiction - in most jurisdictions you will get a maximum of 2.5Gbps or less - again before overheads, and not real-world numbers.